# Setup multifinger trackpad gestures

Tags: touchpad, libinput

I am switching over from Windows and one thing that I really miss are the trackpad gestures. Swiping up with 3 fingers displays all windows, swiping down with 3 fingers minimizes all windows, swiping left or right brings you to the next window. How do I set this up in Ubuntu? I've tried touchegg and libinput-gestures but these do not seem to be working.